# DbProviderFactories configSource error

Tags: .net

If I try to add configuration->system.data->DbProviderFactories through configSource:

```
<DbProviderFactories configSource="FileName">
```

I get an ConfigurationErrorsException with message "Unrecognized attribute 'config source'"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`system.data` is a configuration section, so can have a configSource attribute.
`DbProviderFactories` is an element within this section, and can't.